# Jquery buscar en input checked el valor de una propiedad

Tags: jquery, html

tengo el siguiente código html

```
<input codprueba="Prueba1" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba1">
<input codprueba="Prueba2" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba2">
<input codprueba="Prueba3" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba3">
```

Y mediante JQuery, quiero concatenar en una variable separado por `"|"`, por ejemplo, el valor que tienen en el atributo `codprueba`.

Esto es, si están checkeados el primer y tercer checkbox que me devolviese 
`var cadena = 'Prueba1|Prueba2'`

A lo que he llegado es al siguiente código, pero no se como seguir.

```
var cadena = $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true).attr("codprueba");

alert(cadena);
```

```js
    var cadena = $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true).attr("codprueba");

    alert(cadena);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input codprueba="Prueba1" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba1">
    <input codprueba="Prueba2" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba2">
    <input codprueba="Prueba3" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba3">
```

Comment: Por curiosidad: qué te hizo decantarte por es respuesta y no por la que marcaste  primero ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que recorrer todos los `input` seleccionados para consultar uno a uno sus valores e insertarlos en un array o ir formando ya la cadena de caracteres según el formato que precises.

```
var selected = [];
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('codprueba'));
});
alert(selected);
```

Para evitar conflictos con otros input te recomiendo que uses la propiedad `name` para nombrar de manera única estos inputs. De este modo podrías hacer:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=my_name]:checked").each(function(){
    selected.push($(this).attr('codprueba'));
});
```

También puedes insertarlos dentro de un `div` con un `id` y seleccionar los inputs dentro de ese div:

```
$('#my_div_id input:checked')...
```

Para unir el array bastaría con la siguiente sentencia:

```
var str = selected.join("|");
```

Comment: @lois6b Gracias por el comentario, me había centrado solamente el obtener todos seleccionados.

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar los valores de los `checkbox` que están marcados utiliza lo siguiente (Yo les he puesto el atributo `name`):

```
var yourArray = new Array();

$("input:checkbox[name=checks]:checked").each(function(){
    yourArray.push($(this).attr('codprueba'));
});
```

Tus `checkbox` serán declarados de la siguiente manera:

```
<input codprueba="Prueba1" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba1" name="checks" checked>
<input codprueba="Prueba2" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba2" name="checks" checked>
<input codprueba="Prueba3" type="checkbox" title="Observaciones Prueba3" name="checks" >
```

*El atributo `checked` lo he puesto para depurar*

Para escribir el resultado tal y como lo quieres sería:

```
 document.write(yourArray.join("|"));
```

Comment: Cierto! La verdad que no había caído! Editado :) @lois6b

Answer (score 0):

Para asegurar que los input contienen el attributo "codprueba" usar selector "input[codprueba]:checked" para recorrer todos los input. Aquí el ejemplo de código:

```
var arr = [];
$.map($("input[codprueba]:checked"), function(elem) {
    arr.push($(elem).attr("codprueba"));
}
var result = arr.join("|");
```